# calculating a range based on the fields of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

d = pd.DataFrame({
       'col': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
       'start': [1, 4, 6, 8], 
       'end': [4, 9, 10, 12]
    })
```

I'm trying to calculate a range field based on start and end fields such that the values for it are

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

I have tried the following options

```
d['range_'] = np.arange( d.start, d.end, 1)


d['range_'] = range(d['start'], d['end'])
```

but get the following errors

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

TypeError: 'Series' object cannot be interpreted as an integer  <- second attempt

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
d.apply(lambda x: np.arange(x['start'], x['end']+1), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0          [1, 2, 3, 4]
1    [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
2      [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
3    [8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
dtype: object
```

***Note:*** `np.arange` and `range` are not designed to accept pd.Series, therefore you can use apply rowwise to create ranges.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
l = [list(range(x,y+1)) for x , y in zip(d.start,d.end)]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]
d['range_']=l
```